# NXOAuth2Client in swift based single view iOS app: how to import the library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I'd like to use [NXOAuth2Client](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client) In my single view iOS *swift* app; therefore I'added the library to my project using CocoaPods. I open the workspace and the project builds successfully.

the tutorial I'm following in in objective-c and, at some point, in `AppDelegate.m` they:

```
#import "NXOAuth2.h"
```

but when I'm trying to do the same in my `AppDelegate.swift` I always get `No such module` ; for example if I try:

```
import NXOAuth2Client
```

I get:

> No such module NXOAuth2Client

( the same if I try: `import NXOAuth2` )

I looked at [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) but I'm not experienced enough to figure out what to do in my case.

Here my workspace structure:
[image: worspace]

Need I to add `Bridging-Header.h` ? how it works and where I put it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Podfile is wrong. you need to make it use frameworks with swift.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'xyzPod'
end
```

Comment: adding ```platform :ios , '8.0'``` and ```use_frameworks!``` doesn't help , even if I close  XCode and run a new ```pod install``` ; **but** I took a look at https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/
http://www.basedb.net/Index/detail/id/467157.html and decided to add a Bridging-Header.h and this solved

Comment: sorry @Daij-Djan, my fault: Your answer solves too, but I need also to ```import NXOAuth2Client```;  by adding Bridging-Header.h it works ( build successful ) without adding imports; Please could edit your answer and give an explanation for this ?

Comment: well, a bridging header actually does an import in a way ... the swift code just needs to SEE the objC library :) -- but the header, you have to maintain yourself :/